# Best way to configure e-mail custom variables on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an application that send an e-mail to admin recipient. In development, it has a value of dev@mydomain.com and in production it have prod@mydomain.com . What is the best way to configure this kind of things in Rails?
I want to use something like this:

```
mail(to: my.delivery.mail, :subject "whatever")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways, but the simplest is:

```
recipient = Rails.env.production? ? 'prod@mydomain.com' : 'dev@mydomain.com'
mail(to: recipient, :subject "whatevs...")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using environment variables

```
mail(:to => ENV['ADMIN_ADDRESS'], :subject => "whatever")
```

you then set them on deployment (through capistrano or whatever tool). This information is not business logic (so it does not belong to the app) nor business data (so it does not belong to the database). That's what environment is for.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple environment you can set a method(mainly in mailer class) and set admin recipient,
or write into environments file `config.admin_mail =dev@mydomain.com` and in `mail(to: AppName::Application.config.admin_email,..)`